# Why aren't unsigned integer types available in the top database platforms?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datatypes

Databases are usually very customizable with varying data types and custom lengths.

It surprises me, as I try to look for the syntax to use `unsigned int` types that they are not available from neither PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server. MySQL and Oracle seem to.

This seems like a glaring omission on their part - the next best perfomant option being a long/bigint, (8 byte integer), but could be completely unneccessary! Does anyone know why they would choose to not include native unsigned int support?

Comment: Why would you want to use an `unsigned int`? (The only portable guarantee you have on that type in C is that it can hold numbers up to 65535.)

Comment: I would want to use unsigned numeric types when I want twice the range and I have no use for negative values. Ints are usually 4 bytes, so 0 to 4,294,967,295 instead of –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: Why would they be two-byte integers in C? What's a `portable guarantee`? I supposed I'm just used to Microsoft data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Portable == standard mandated. The C standard does not specify the width of ordinary ints or longs, just minimum ranges of representable numbers. Platforms with 16bit ints were common at some point. 64bit is possible. 36 too (though extinct). 24 happens (DSPs).  How often is it that you have data the fits in 32bit but not 31, _and_ that you've measured that using ordinary numeric types gives you a performance hit?

Comment: Both SQL-Server and Postgres has `NUMERIC(10)` which allows integers up to `9.999.999.999` (and with a constraint you can disallow negative values.)

Comment: For one reason: they are not specified in the SQL standard. For a more lengthy discussion regarding Postgres take a look at this discussion: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/RFC-Unsigned-integer-support-td1987008.html and this: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Unsigned-integer-types-td5756994.html

Comment: For SQL Server [an explanation is here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/515502/unsigned-integer-data-type)

Comment: @Mat It's not the performance hit I'm worried about, it's 4 extra bytes x 153 million = ~612 extra MB wasted, the values go above 3 billion but not 4 billion. A numeric(10) has performace hits in addition to requiring 9 bytes of storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: If size on disk is the issue, SQL-Server offers data compression (but I think only the Enterpise editions.) Postgres can be setup so one or more tables are stored in a compressed filesystem.

Comment: I don't have enterprise edition SQL Server and I'm not looking to switch database platforms here - I just want unsigned ints in SQL Server and I'm surprised they are missing.

Comment: @MartinSmith the explanation in the link you posted is exactly the answer I was looking for, could you write that up as an answer?

Comment: Oracle does not support unsigned integers the way you are asking for in SQL Server. The database does not support binary integers http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209. And PL/SQL looks to be restricting the range of the base `binary_integer` (32 bit 2s complement signed integer.) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i46029

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Microsoft's Jim Hogg has responded to this issue with the following:

> There are pros and cons. On the pro side, it seems like a good way to avoid some errors - having to check a (signed) int has value > 0. And I would also venture that many uses of int in fact relate to counts that should never be negative anyway. On the question of doubling max row count? - true, but I would say this is less compelling.
>
> On the cons side ... mixing signed/unsigned types in C or C++ seems like it should be simple enough. It's not. It opens a small tarpit of hard-to-find mistakes - most due to the complex rules for implicit promotions/widenings. SQL, alas, already has an even more complex set of implicits casting rules. Adding unsigned ints, I fear, would confuse us all even more.
>
> I'll keep this suggestion on the books. But, among all the features we could/should be adding, this one, with respect, is not near the top of that list.

Source: [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/515502/unsigned-integer-data-type)

I would add significantly to the pro list, and reiterate that their SQL engine is already doing FAR more complex things than this, and so their team can handle the added complexity. While I don't agree with their summation, this is *Why SQL Server doesn't support unsigned types*.

The Connect link was originally posted by [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) in the question comments.

Comment: "confuse us all even more" - probably refers to everyone using SQL Server, not just their own development team.

Comment: I wish they'd have a `SET NO_1970s_SQL_BOLLOCKS ON` option to SQL Server so we can dispense with unneeded implicit narrowing conversions. Is the aim of ISO SQL compliance still worthwhile at all considering how horrible ISO SQL is nowadays, and the fact there has never been portability for non-trivial queries between RDBMS? Meanwhile it's 2021 and the lack of support for deferrable-constraints, macros, and sane change-tracking, let alone unsigned integers, is driving me up the wall :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very old; the OP mentioned the need for unsigned int for probably one of two reasons.

1. the values recorded are only positive and thus a potential storage saving from using a smaller type (bitwise)
2. it's an identity an the OP is trying to reduce the key size.

This previously perplexed me as well, my work-around for (1) was to use views and SP's to ensure that the DB stores the smaller value but that the representation always adjust for it – not ideal but the space saving offset the cost of CPU cycles.

For (2) I've simply always started my identity seed at the greatest negative number -32768 for a smallint – still not ideal but it works and doubles the keyspace available vs starting from the traditional counter of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was asking as I was looking to store a lot of values that ranged from 0 to 2,851,254,831 and this is just north of the upper limit for signed 32 bit integers - 2,147,483,547. An unsigned 32 bit integer would store this just fine, as the maximum is 4,294,967,295. By storing as a signed Int32 and then converting out when I want the unsigned, I can indeed keep my storage space down. And I never thought about starting my identity columns negative before!

Comment: how about 64b `bigint`? There is no bigger datatype to store and process unsigned 64b.