# Unsigned Int datatypes

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

Does Microsoft SQL Server support *unsigned* integer data types?

I am trying to learn a bit more about the data type choices and helping a friend in his database project, I know that MySQL does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The numeric data types are all signed.

For example an int is from approx. -2^31 to +2^31.

If you have a value just shy of 2^32 you will have to use a larger data type such as bigint. There are finer points here, but out of scope of this discussion.

Related Q & A:

[Why aren't unsigned integer types available in the top database platforms?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53050/1192)

Documentation:

- [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)
- [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: `TINYINT` isn't signed

Comment: Neither is `bit` :D

Answer (score 0):

You can easily emulate unsigned 32-bit int with your regular, signed bigint. Do whatever arithmetics needs to be done, AND with 0xFFFFFFFF for every operation that may potentially overflow the lower 32 bits.

Comment: Doing `AND 0xFFFFFFFF` would just sweep-under-the-rug any overflow issues - I feel a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to set a bounds on the range would be better as that would throw an error on overflow rather than hiding it. Another problem with using a wider type (e.g. `bigint` instead of a hypothetical `utin32`) is that you end-up wasting 4 bytes per column per record, which could add-up. In a recent application I built I ended-up storing `uint64` values as signed `bigint` values and transforming values (and query parameters) at the last minute - which added more complexity.

Comment: It's up to the OP how to handle that. Some algorithms *depend* on silent overflow.